# Fixing the canvas offset in Raphael.js when DOM element centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, geometry

I'm creating circles in a Raphael.js Canvas with a clicking action. When the canvas is drawn at the origin of the website it works fine. **But when I move it to the middle some type offseting happens and only when you click on the right side of the canvas the circles are drawn at the left side of the canvas**. Even though I have my listener action to the canvas and not the div that the   is append to, here is the code:

```
<body>
 <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var canvas = Raphael("container", 500, 500);
var ourCanvas = $('svg').last();
ourCanvas.attr("id", "canvas");
var canvasHandler = $("#canvas");
//We create a div with a class to append our canvas
var containerHandler = $("#container");
var circleClass = $("circle.quincy");
var justDragged = false;
canvasHandler.mouseup(function (e) {
var mouseX = e.pageX;
var mouseY = e.pageY;
makeCircle(mouseX, mouseY);
});



function makeCircle(mouseX, mouseY) {
 var radius;
 var fill;
 var thisCirclesID = String(new Date().getTime());
 var circle = canvas.circle(mouseX, mouseY, 50).attr({
     fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
     stroke: "none",
     opacity: .5,
 });
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mauricioSanchez/n2N3e/)

I wonder if the way that I'm using the event position is correct. Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Thanks

M

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything for me, I just get a grey box, no circles.

Comment: if you click close to the edge on the left side you will see the circles appearing on the other side partially. I fixed using the offsetParent method. Here is the old http://jsfiddle.net/mauricioSanchez/n2N3e/ and here is a new one http://jsfiddle.net/mauricioSanchez/Cys95/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after realizing that the offset of the new position of svg was causing the mouse event to not recognize its real position. I found this blog [post](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) that shows how to use the offsetParent method to calculate the new position of my canvas relative its parent . Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//We create our canvas and add an ID
var canvas = Raphael("container", 500, 500);
var ourCanvas = $('svg').last();
ourCanvas.attr("id", "canvas");
var canvasHandler = $("#canvas");
//We create a div with a class to append our canvas
var containerHandler = $("#container");
var circleClass = $("circle.quincy");
var justDragged = false;
canvasHandler.mouseup(function (e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX - findPos(this)[0];
    var mouseY = e.pageY - findPos(this)[1];
    makeCircle(mouseX, mouseY);
    findPos(this);
    console.log("This is the position of the mouse in X: " + e.pageX);
    console.log("This is the position of the mouse in Y: " + e.pageY);
});

 function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj == obj.offsetParent);
        console.log(curleft);
        console.log(curtop);
        // return [curleft, curtop];
    }
    return [curleft, curtop];
}
```

As you can see the findPos(obj) returns and array of the new position of X and Y. So I substract that to my mouseX and mouseY to get the real position on the svg when clicking.

**Update**

Doing more reading and asking around. I didn't realize what type of elements the web browser returns. Instead of using e.pageX and e.pageY. offsetX offers the position of the mouse in respect to the parent giving the real coordinates. So the code will look like this:

```
canvasHandler.mouseup(function (e) {
var mouseX = e.offsetX;
var mouseY = e.offsetY;
makeCircle(mouseX, mouseY);
findPos(this);
```

});

This makes it easier since the offset takes into consideration the real position of the mouse in respect to the  element.